# How to search recursively for the closest active manager

Tags: powershell

The script gets an employee's Id number and it needs  to print the information of the closest "ACTIVE" manager of the requested employee.
Not all the managers are "ACTIVE" some of them may be "INACTIVE", therefore i need to search for the closest active manager recursively.

Comment: What is the data source and how is it structured? What does "closest" mean? Does each manager's information include polar coordinates? Is this homework? What specific problem and error messages are you finding?

Answer (score 0):

There is really not much to go on here in the question. `Get-UserActiveManage` would probably more aptly named `Get-Employee`. Naturally, I have not tested this, but something along these lines may work. Think through the steps for every loop condition.

```
$employee = $item
$manager = $null

while (($item.WorkStatusTypeCd -ne $null) -and ($item.WorkStatusTypeCd -eq "ACTIVE")) {
    $managerId = $item.ManagerId
    $item = Get-UserActiveManager -searchType ID -searchString $managerId
    if (($item.WorkStatusTypeCd -ne $null) -and ($item.WorkStatusTypeCd -eq 'ACTIVE')) {
        ### This is the manager.
        $manager = $item
    } elseif ($item.ManagerId -eq $null) {
        ### The end. No manager can be found.
    }
}

'{0} is the manager of {1}' -f $($manager.EmployeeId, $employee.EmployeeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is probably similar to lit's, but reading his answer got confusing for me so I'm writing my own.

```
$employee = $item
$manager = Get-UserActiveManager -searchType ID -searchString $item.ManagerId

# If the manager is not active, get that manager's manager until we find an active one
While($Manager.WorkStatusTypeCd -ne 'Active'){
    $manager = Get-UserActiveManager -searchType ID -searchString $Manager.ManagerId
}
```

Comment: If the function won't return inactive employee IDs, how do you expect to work your way up the chain? It sounds like you need to fix the function before attempting this portion of the script.